# ANTLR4: lexer debugging/tracing

Tags: debugging, antlr4, lexer, trace

How can I debug/trace/dump the paths the ANTLR4-generated lexer chooses? Many times I am out of luck to see in the grammar itself what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ANTLRWorks](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks). Under *run -> Interpret lexer* you can see the output for the lexer grammar. Maybe also click *Window -> Lexer debugger Controller window*, if it's not automatically displayed. Under it, you can see types, tokens, channels, modes, lookahead. Tokens are quite useful to see which "string" was recognized as which token.  Also, if I have lexer modes I always use antlrworks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :-)

Comment: But does AntlrWorks ork for Antlr4 ? On the homepage I see only Antlr3

Comment: @Devid Yes, I use it only with Antlr4

Comment: @cantSleepNow yes I see now, but it is called ANTLRWorks2.

Comment: Yes it is, if that was a question :)This is what it writes when I click on help->about, the first line only: *Product Version: ANTLRWorks 2 20130716-5d2e7d936ca1*

Answer (score 2):

The Intellij ANTLR plugin is very good for debugging ANTLR grammars. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130989/721855