# How to debug ANTLR4 grammar extraneous / mismatched input error

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I want to parse the Rulebook "demo.rb" files like below:

```
rulebook Titanic-Normalization {
  version 1

  meta {
    description "Test"
    source "my-rules.xslx"
    user "joltie"
  }

  rule remove-first-line {
    description "Removes first line when offset is zero"
    when(present(offset) && offset == 0) then {
      filter-row-if-true true;
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the ANTLR4 grammar file Rulebook.g4 like below. For now, it can parse the *.rb files generally well, but it throw unexpected error when encounter the "expression" / "statement" rules.

```
grammar Rulebook;

rulebookStatement
    :   KWRulebook
        (GeneralIdentifier | Identifier)
        '{'
        KWVersion
        VersionConstant
        metaStatement
        (ruleStatement)+
        '}'
    ;

metaStatement
    :   KWMeta
        '{'
        KWDescription
        StringLiteral
        KWSource
        StringLiteral
        KWUser
        StringLiteral
        '}'
    ;

ruleStatement
    :   KWRule
        (GeneralIdentifier | Identifier)
        '{'
        KWDescription
        StringLiteral
        whenThenStatement
        '}'
    ;

whenThenStatement
    :   KWWhen '(' expression ')'
        KWThen '{' statement '}'
    ;

primaryExpression
    :   GeneralIdentifier
    |   Identifier
    |   StringLiteral+
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;

postfixExpression
    :   primaryExpression
    |   postfixExpression '[' expression ']'
    |   postfixExpression '(' argumentExpressionList? ')'
    |   postfixExpression '.' Identifier
    |   postfixExpression '->' Identifier
    |   postfixExpression '++'
    |   postfixExpression '--'
    ;

argumentExpressionList
    :   assignmentExpression
    |   argumentExpressionList ',' assignmentExpression
    ;

unaryExpression
    :   postfixExpression
    |   '++' unaryExpression
    |   '--' unaryExpression
    |   unaryOperator castExpression
    ;

unaryOperator
    :   '&' | '*' | '+' | '-' | '~' | '!'
    ;

castExpression
    :   unaryExpression
    |   DigitSequence // for
    ;

multiplicativeExpression
    :   castExpression
    |   multiplicativeExpression '*' castExpression
    |   multiplicativeExpression '/' castExpression
    |   multiplicativeExpression '%' castExpression
    ;

additiveExpression
    :   multiplicativeExpression
    |   additiveExpression '+' multiplicativeExpression
    |   additiveExpression '-' multiplicativeExpression
    ;

shiftExpression
    :   additiveExpression
    |   shiftExpression '<<' additiveExpression
    |   shiftExpression '>>' additiveExpression
    ;

relationalExpression
    :   shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '<' shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '>' shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '<=' shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '>=' shiftExpression
    ;

equalityExpression
    :   relationalExpression
    |   equalityExpression '==' relationalExpression
    |   equalityExpression '!=' relationalExpression
    ;

andExpression
    :   equalityExpression
    |   andExpression '&' equalityExpression
    ;

exclusiveOrExpression
    :   andExpression
    |   exclusiveOrExpression '^' andExpression
    ;

inclusiveOrExpression
    :   exclusiveOrExpression
    |   inclusiveOrExpression '|' exclusiveOrExpression
    ;

logicalAndExpression
    :   inclusiveOrExpression
    |   logicalAndExpression '&&' inclusiveOrExpression
    ;

logicalOrExpression
    :   logicalAndExpression
    |   logicalOrExpression '||' logicalAndExpression
    ;

conditionalExpression
    :   logicalOrExpression ('?' expression ':' conditionalExpression)?
    ;

assignmentExpression
    :   conditionalExpression
    |   unaryExpression assignmentOperator assignmentExpression
    |   DigitSequence // for
    ;

assignmentOperator
    :   '=' | '*=' | '/=' | '%=' | '+=' | '-=' | '<<=' | '>>=' | '&=' | '^=' | '|='
    ;

expression
    :   assignmentExpression
    |   expression ',' assignmentExpression
    ;

statement
    :   expressionStatement
    ;

expressionStatement
    :   expression+ ';'
    ;


KWRulebook: 'rulebook';
KWVersion: 'version';
KWMeta: 'meta';
KWDescription: 'description';
KWSource: 'source';
KWUser: 'user';
KWRule: 'rule';
KWWhen: 'when';
KWThen: 'then';
KWTrue: 'true';
KWFalse: 'false';

fragment
LeftParen : '(';

fragment
RightParen : ')';

fragment
LeftBracket : '[';

fragment
RightBracket : ']';

fragment
LeftBrace : '{';

fragment
RightBrace : '}';


Identifier
    :   IdentifierNondigit
        (   IdentifierNondigit
        |   Digit
        )*
    ;

GeneralIdentifier
    :   Identifier
        ('-' Identifier)+
    ;

fragment
IdentifierNondigit
    :   Nondigit
    //|   // other implementation-defined characters...
    ;

VersionConstant
    :   DigitSequence ('.' DigitSequence)*
    ;

DigitSequence
    :   Digit+
    ;

fragment
Nondigit
    :   [a-zA-Z_]
    ;

fragment
Digit
    :   [0-9]
    ;

StringLiteral
    :   '"' SCharSequence? '"'
    |   '\'' SCharSequence? '\''
    ;

fragment
SCharSequence
    :   SChar+
    ;

fragment
SChar
    :   ~["\\\r\n]
    |   '\\\n'   // Added line
    |   '\\\r\n' // Added line
    ;

Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
        -> skip
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> skip
    ;

BlockComment
    :   '/*' .*? '*/'
        -> skip
    ;

LineComment
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
        -> skip
    ;
```

I tested the Rulebook parser with unit test like below:

```
    public void testScanRulebookFile() throws IOException {
        String fileName = "C:\\rulebooks\\demo.rb";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        // create a CharStream that reads from standard input
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromStream(fis);

        // create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
        RulebookLexer lexer = new RulebookLexer(input);

        // create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        // create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
        RulebookParser parser = new RulebookParser(tokens);


        RulebookStatementContext context = parser.rulebookStatement();
//        WhenThenStatementContext context = parser.whenThenStatement();

        System.out.println(context.toStringTree(parser));

//      ParseTree tree = parser.getContext(); // begin parsing at init rule
//      System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print LISP-style tree
    }
```

For the "demo.rb" as above, the parser got the error as below. I also print the RulebookStatementContext as toStringTree.

```
line 12:25 mismatched input '&&' expecting ')'
(rulebookStatement rulebook Titanic-Normalization { version 1 (metaStatement meta { description "Test" source "my-rules.xslx" user "joltie" }) (ruleStatement rule remove-first-line { description "Removes first line when offset is zero" (whenThenStatement when ( (expression (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (logicalOrExpression (logicalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (castExpression (unaryExpression (postfixExpression (postfixExpression (primaryExpression present)) ( (argumentExpressionList (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (logicalOrExpression (logicalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (castExpression (unaryExpression (postfixExpression (primaryExpression offset))))))))))))))))) ))))))))))))))))) && offset == 0 ) then { filter-row-if-true true ;) }) })
```

I also write the unit test to test short input context like `"when (offset == 0) then {\n" + "filter-row-if-true true;\n" + "}\n"` to debug the problem. But it still got the error like:

```
line 1:16 mismatched input '0' expecting {'(', '++', '--', '&&', '&', '*', '+', '-', '~', '!', Identifier, GeneralIdentifier, DigitSequence, StringLiteral}
line 2:19 extraneous input 'true' expecting {'(', '++', '--', '&&', '&', '*', '+', '-', '~', '!', ';', Identifier, GeneralIdentifier, DigitSequence, StringLiteral}
```

With two day's tries, I didn't got any progress. The question is so long as above, please someone give me some advises about **how to debug ANTLR4 grammar extraneous / mismatched input error**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any more sophisticated methods to debug a grammar/parser but here's how I usally do it:

1. Reduce the input that causes the problem to as few characters as
   possible.
2. Reduce your grammar as far as possible so that it still produces the same error on the respective input (most of the time that means wrinting a minimal grammar for the reduced input by recycling the rules of the original grammar (simplifying as far as possible)
3. Make sure the lexer segments the input properly (for that the feature in ANTLRWorks that shows you the lexer output is great)
4. Have a look at the ParseTree. ANTLR's testRig has a feature that displays the ParseTree graphically (You can access this functionality either through ANTLRWorks or by ANTLR's `TreeViewer`) so you can have a look where the parser's interpretation differs from the one you have
5. Do the parsing "by hand". That means you will take your grammar and go through the input by yourself, step by step and try to apply no logic or assumptions/knowledge/etc. during that process. Just follow through your own grammar as a computer would do it. Question every step you take (Is there another way to match the input) and always try to match the input in another way than the one you actually want it to be parsed

Try to fix the error in the minimal grammar and migrate the solution to your real grammar afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your detail help. I have tried the 1. 2. 5. points but I think I should try more to split the input & grammar. Could you help me with this specific example as above if you are available.

Comment: Have you had a look at the parse tree?

Comment: Yeah. I have look at the parse tree as you pointed in point 5.. I also read many same problem in stackoverflow but the result was strange. I am trying to write "whenThenStatement" rule unit test with simple grammar and simple input.

Comment: So the only problem is the if-statement? (or rather when-statement) Normally that would look something like `'when' boolean 'then' '{' normalCode '}'`

Comment: Oh and BTW... If you'd use direct left recursion in your rules it would simplify your grammar a lot...

Comment: I use some left recursion but what is the direct left recursion mean?

Comment: Oh my bad... I just skimmed your grammar and didn't pay enough attention... Direct left-recursion is just the one you have implemented

Comment: This is a good list. Reducing the string and grammar both is good way to narrow down the problem. Even after that if you're unable to find the problem, relook at every lexer rule (ones starting with capital letters) first and make them as mutually exclusive as you can. Most issues I have come across are because of ambiguity there

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Raven answer I have used the Intellij 12+ Plugin for ANTLR 4 and it saved me a lot of effort debugging a grammar. I had a very simple bug (unescaped dot . instead of '.' in a floating number rule) that I could not find. This tool allows to select any parser rule of the grammar, test it with an input and shows graphically the parsing tree. I didn't notice it has this very useful feature until I started searching for ways to debug the grammar. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Update the g4 file to fix parsing error

```
grammar Rulebook;       

@header {
package com.someone.commons.rulebook.parser;
}

rulebookStatement
    :   KWRulebook
        (GeneralIdentifier | Identifier)
        '{'
        KWVersion
        VersionConstant
        metaStatement
        (ruleStatement)+
        '}'
    ;

metaStatement
    :   KWMeta
        '{'
        KWDescription
        StringLiteral
        KWSource
        StringLiteral
        KWUser
        StringLiteral
        '}'
    ;

ruleStatement
    :   KWRule
        (GeneralIdentifier | Identifier)
        '{'
        KWDescription
        StringLiteral
        whenThenStatement
        '}'
    ;

whenThenStatement
    :   KWWhen '(' expression ')'
        KWThen '{' (statement)* '}'
    ;

primaryExpression
    :   GeneralIdentifier
    |   Identifier
    |   StringLiteral+
    |   Constant
    |   '(' expression ')'
    |   '[' expression ']'
    ;

postfixExpression
    :   primaryExpression
    |   postfixExpression '[' expression ']'
    |   postfixExpression '(' argumentExpressionList? ')'
    |   postfixExpression '.' Identifier
    |   postfixExpression '->' Identifier
    |   postfixExpression '++'
    |   postfixExpression '--'
    ;

argumentExpressionList
    :   assignmentExpression
    |   argumentExpressionList ',' assignmentExpression
    ;

unaryExpression
    :   postfixExpression
    |   '++' unaryExpression
    |   '--' unaryExpression
    |   unaryOperator castExpression
    ;

unaryOperator
    :   '&' | '*' | '+' | '-' | '~' | '!'
    ;

castExpression
    :   unaryExpression
    ;

multiplicativeExpression
    :   castExpression
    |   multiplicativeExpression '*' castExpression
    |   multiplicativeExpression '/' castExpression
    |   multiplicativeExpression '%' castExpression
    ;

additiveExpression
    :   multiplicativeExpression
    |   additiveExpression '+' multiplicativeExpression
    |   additiveExpression '-' multiplicativeExpression
    ;

shiftExpression
    :   additiveExpression
    |   shiftExpression '<<' additiveExpression
    |   shiftExpression '>>' additiveExpression
    ;

relationalExpression
    :   shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '<' shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '>' shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '<=' shiftExpression
    |   relationalExpression '>=' shiftExpression
    ;

equalityExpression
    :   relationalExpression
    |   equalityExpression '==' relationalExpression
    |   equalityExpression '!=' relationalExpression
    ;

andExpression
    :   equalityExpression
    |   andExpression '&' equalityExpression
    ;

exclusiveOrExpression
    :   andExpression
    |   exclusiveOrExpression '^' andExpression
    ;

inclusiveOrExpression
    :   exclusiveOrExpression
    |   inclusiveOrExpression '|' exclusiveOrExpression
    ;

logicalAndExpression
    :   inclusiveOrExpression
    |   logicalAndExpression '&&' inclusiveOrExpression
    ;

logicalOrExpression
    :   logicalAndExpression
    |   logicalOrExpression '||' logicalAndExpression
    ;

conditionalExpression
    :   logicalOrExpression ('?' expression? ':' conditionalExpression)?
    ;

assignmentExpression
    :   conditionalExpression
    |   unaryExpression assignmentOperator assignmentExpression
    ;

assignmentOperator
    :   '=' | '*=' | '/=' | '%=' | '+=' | '-=' | '<<=' | '>>=' | '&=' | '^=' | '|='
    ;

expression
    :   assignmentExpression
    |   expression ',' assignmentExpression
    ;

statement
    :   expressionStatement
    ;

expressionStatement
    :   expression+ ';'
    ;


KWRulebook: 'rulebook';
KWVersion: 'version';
KWMeta: 'meta';
KWDescription: 'description';
KWSource: 'source';
KWUser: 'user';
KWRule: 'rule';
KWWhen: 'when';
KWThen: 'then';

Identifier
    :   IdentifierNondigit
        (   IdentifierNondigit
        |   Digit
        )*
    ;

GeneralIdentifier
    :   Identifier
        (   '-' 
        |   '.'
        |   IdentifierNondigit
        |   Digit
        )*
    ;

fragment
IdentifierNondigit
    :   Nondigit
    //|   // other implementation-defined characters...
    ;

VersionConstant
    :   DigitSequence ('.' DigitSequence)*
    ;

Constant
    :   IntegerConstant
    |   FloatingConstant
    ;

fragment
IntegerConstant
    :   DecimalConstant
    ;

fragment
DecimalConstant
    :   NonzeroDigit Digit*
    ;

fragment
FloatingConstant
    :   DecimalFloatingConstant
    ;

fragment
DecimalFloatingConstant
    :   FractionalConstant
    ;

fragment
FractionalConstant
    :   DigitSequence? '.' DigitSequence
    |   DigitSequence '.'
    ;

fragment
DigitSequence
    :   Digit+
    ;

fragment
Nondigit
    :   [a-zA-Z_]
    ;

fragment
Digit
    :   [0-9]
    ;

fragment
NonzeroDigit
    :   [1-9]
    ;

StringLiteral
    :   '"' SCharSequence? '"'
    |   '\'' SCharSequence? '\''
    ;

fragment
SCharSequence
    :   SChar+
    ;

fragment
SChar
    :   ~["\\\r\n]
    |   '\\\n'   // Added line
    |   '\\\r\n' // Added line
    ;

Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
        -> skip
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> skip
    ;

BlockComment
    :   '/*' .*? '*/'
        -> skip
    ;

LineComment
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
        -> skip
    ;
```